# python pandas not reading first column from csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a simple 2 column csv file called st1.csv:

```
GRID    St1  
1457    614  
1458    657  
1459    679  
1460    732  
1461    754  
1462    811  
1463    748
```

However, when I try to read the csv file, the first column is not loaded:

```
a = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('st1.csv')  
a.columns
```

**outputs:**

```
 Index([u'ST1'], dtype=object)
```

Why is the first column not being read?

Comment: It's assuming that the first column is the index, try a = `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('st1.csv', index_col=False)`

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: I am facing the exact opposite issue when I read a csv that was compressed (using python, pandas). any explanation for why it wasn't following behaviour?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Judging by your data it looks like the delimiter you're using is a  .

Try the following:

```
a = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('st1.csv', sep=' ')
```

The other issue is that it's assuming your first column is an index, which we can also disable:

```
a = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('st1.csv', index_col=None)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

In newer pandas versions, do:

```
a = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('st1.csv', index_col=False)
```

Comment: interesting that in the docs there is no mention of setting index_col=False, but that's definitely part of the solution: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html

Comment: In Python 3: index_col=False throws an error, I used index_col=None and it works fine...

Comment: I agree with @Grant, you have to use index_col=None (even in Python 2).

Comment: @Grant & Tom - I have updated my answer to reflect this. Thank you for informing me.

Comment: Python 3.5 and pandas 0.21.1: `index_col = False` worked fine, but `index_col = None` was ignored. Strange.

Answer (score 12):

For newer versions of pandas, `pd.DataFrame.from_csv` doesn't exist anymore, and `index_col=None` no longer does the trick with `pd.read_csv`. **You'll want to use `pd.read_csv` with `index_col=False` instead**:

```
pd.read_csv('st1.csv', index_col=False)
```

Example:

```
(so) URSA-MattM-MacBook:stackoverflow mmessersmith$ cat input.csv 
Date                        Employee        Operation        Order

2001-01-01 08:32:17         User1           Approved         #00045
2001-01-01 08:36:23         User1           Edited           #00045
2001-01-01 08:41:04         User1           Rejected         #00046
2001-01-01 08:42:56         User1           Deleted          #00046
2001-01-02 09:01:11         User1           Created          #00047
2019-10-03 17:23:45         User1           Approved         #72681

(so) URSA-MattM-MacBook:stackoverflow mmessersmith$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.25.1'              
>>> df_bad_index = pd.read_csv('input.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
>>> df_bad_index
                Date Employee Operation   Order
2001-01-01  08:32:17    User1  Approved  #00045
2001-01-01  08:36:23    User1    Edited  #00045
2001-01-01  08:41:04    User1  Rejected  #00046
2001-01-01  08:42:56    User1   Deleted  #00046
2001-01-02  09:01:11    User1   Created  #00047
2019-10-03  17:23:45    User1  Approved  #72681
>>> df_bad_index.index
Index(['2001-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-02',
       '2019-10-03'],
      dtype='object')
>>> df_still_bad_index = pd.read_csv('input.csv', delim_whitespace=True, index_col=None)
>>> df_still_bad_index
                Date Employee Operation   Order
2001-01-01  08:32:17    User1  Approved  #00045
2001-01-01  08:36:23    User1    Edited  #00045
2001-01-01  08:41:04    User1  Rejected  #00046
2001-01-01  08:42:56    User1   Deleted  #00046
2001-01-02  09:01:11    User1   Created  #00047
2019-10-03  17:23:45    User1  Approved  #72681
>>> df_still_bad_index.index
Index(['2001-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-02',
       '2019-10-03'],
      dtype='object')
>>> df_good_index = pd.read_csv('input.csv', delim_whitespace=True, index_col=False)
>>> df_good_index
         Date  Employee Operation     Order
0  2001-01-01  08:32:17     User1  Approved
1  2001-01-01  08:36:23     User1    Edited
2  2001-01-01  08:41:04     User1  Rejected
3  2001-01-01  08:42:56     User1   Deleted
4  2001-01-02  09:01:11     User1   Created
5  2019-10-03  17:23:45     User1  Approved
>>> df_good_index.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=6, step=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on documentation which compares `read_csv` and `from_csv`, it shows that it is possible to put `index_col = None`. I tried the below and it worked:

```
DataFrame.from_csv('st1.csv', index_col=None);
```

This assumes that the data is comma-separated.

Please check the below link

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html