# Column name and corresponding data are not matching in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file n while working on it in python I am facing following problem:

CSV file:

```
   cand_id   cand_name   cand_age   cand_sex
      A1         Adam        35         M
      A2         Max         31         M
      A3         Uma         32         F
      B1         Jack        29         M
      B2         Maya        30         F
```

Now after loading it in python, the out file has become something like this:

```
     cand_id   cand_name   cand_age   cand_sex
       Adam        35         M          NaN
       Max         31         M          NaN
       Uma         32         F          NaN
       Jack        29         M          NaN
       Maya        30         F          Nan
```

please tell me how can I align the correct column name with the corresponding data.

Thanks

Comment: How do you load `csv` to `python`? Do you use `df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\s+")` or `df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\t")` or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas not reading first column from csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902080/python-pandas-not-reading-first-column-from-csv-file)

Comment: both '\t' and '\s+' are giving an error so I loaded it simply pd.read.csv(filename). However though the file name is .csv but data is arranged in different columns like excel not like csv in single column separated by space. Can this be a possible reason? Can i load the file with read_excel instead of csv?

Comment: Is possible share your `csv`? Or better create sample file and share it.

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra Thanks. Tried that already it is not taking first column as index because I am getting result by calling df.ix[2]. Only thing is result is cand_id=Uma instead of cand_id=A3. Similarly for rest of the columns

Comment: @jezrael csv is 700MB+ in size. I am trying to work on the example from 'Python for Data Analysis'  regarding Federal Election Commision DataBase. this is the link for the database http://www.fec.gov/disclosurep/PDownload.do.  Don't know how to create a sample file?

Comment: What file do you use? `ALL.zip` ? Or something else?

Comment: Hello Guys, thanks a lot found the culprit. I was passing col_index=False (in place of index_col=False,and was getting unexpected argument error.)  Sorry for the trouble and thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: @jezrael However I have a doubt if you have time to answer it. When it was taking by default the first column as index , how come I was getting return values on df.ix[2] shouldn't it return the values on df.ix[A3] Sorry but i have just started learning python so have very limited knowledge about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add parameter `index_col=False` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('P00000001-AL.csv', index_col=False)
```

```
print (df.head())
     cmte_id    cand_id                    cand_nm              contbr_nm  \
0  C00574624  P60006111  Cruz, Rafael Edward 'Ted'            LUCAS, FRAN   
1  C00574624  P60006111  Cruz, Rafael Edward 'Ted'  KERR, JOHN MCCLURE II   
2  C00574624  P60006111  Cruz, Rafael Edward 'Ted'    LADD, TEENA E. MRS.   
3  C00574624  P60006111  Cruz, Rafael Edward 'Ted'  KERR, JOHN MCCLURE II   
4  C00574624  P60006111  Cruz, Rafael Edward 'Ted'  KERR, JOHN MCCLURE II   

  contbr_city contbr_st   contbr_zip                   contbr_employer  \
0    FAIRHOPE        AL  365322922.0                     SELF EMPLOYED   
1    HAMILTON        AL  355706637.0  NORTH MISSISSIPPI MEDICAL CENTER   
2     MADISON        AL  357586884.0                           RETIRED   
3    HAMILTON        AL  355706637.0  NORTH MISSISSIPPI MEDICAL CENTER   
4    HAMILTON        AL  355706637.0  NORTH MISSISSIPPI MEDICAL CENTER   

  contbr_occupation  contb_receipt_amt contb_receipt_dt  \
0     COSMETOLOGIST               25.0        27-APR-16   
1         PHYSICIAN             1000.0        28-MAR-16   
2           RETIRED               25.0        20-APR-16   
3         PHYSICIAN             -100.0        30-APR-16   
4         PHYSICIAN              100.0        30-APR-16   

                 receipt_desc memo_cd                   memo_text form_tp  \
0                         NaN     NaN                         NaN   SA17A   
1           SEE REDESIGNATION       X           SEE REDESIGNATION   SA17A   
2                         NaN     NaN                         NaN   SA17A   
3    REDESIGNATION TO GENERAL       X    REDESIGNATION TO GENERAL   SA17A   
4  REDESIGNATION FROM PRIMARY       X  REDESIGNATION FROM PRIMARY   SA17A   

   file_num        tran_id election_tp  
0   1077664  SA17A.1722559       P2016  
1   1077664  SA17A.1675656       P2016  
2   1077664  SA17A.1693960       P2016  
3   1077664  SA17A.1827542       P2016  
4   1077664  SA17A.1827677       G2016
```

EDIT by comment:

```
print (df)
  cand_id cand_name  cand_age cand_sex
0      A1      Adam        35        M
1      A2       Max        31        M
2      A3       Uma        32        F
3      B1      Jack        29        M
4      B2      Maya        30        F

print (df.ix[2])
cand_id       A3
cand_name    Uma
cand_age      32
cand_sex       F
Name: 2, dtype: object

df.set_index('cand_id', inplace=True)
print (df.ix['A3'])
cand_name    Uma
cand_age      32
cand_sex       F
Name: A3, dtype: object
```

Comment: I add solution for selecting, is there some problem? If need set index from column `cand_id`, use `df.set_index('cand_id', inplace=True)`.