# why pandas read_csv assuming that my first column is an index?

Tags: python, pandas

I read csv from text file seperate by comma.

it took me a loot of time to realize that pandas read my first columns as index.

after I read the link below I used "index_col=None "  to cancel it.

[python pandas not reading first column from csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902080/python-pandas-not-reading-first-column-from-csv-file)

the question is :  why, by defult, pandas decide that my first columns is index?

Answer (score 0):

Unless pandas creators are reading here *and* decide to share the reasons behind that specific design decision, you are not going to get a better answer than *because*. It is just an arbitrary design decision which could have easily (50-50 chance)  gone the other way.

For completeness, [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) also writes the index column by default (`index=True`), so **it makes sense** that the default way to write the file will be the default way to read it.